# How to efficiently add method name to Java logging message without typing it in manually?

Tags: java, logging, aop, slf4j

In my Java application, I would like the logs to reflect the calling method name in the message. So that a the following code:

```
void foo(){
   logger.info("some message");
}
```

would result with log message:

```
2020:10:10T10:10:10 thread class #foo some message
```

I am using Logback and SLF4J, and I understand that I can use message template.
To my understanding, this uses reflection and traveling up the call stack, and is a performance hit my team has had issues with in the past.

As an alternative, I looked into AOP, such as AsepectJ. As far as I can find, the calling context is not supplied in any of the AOP libraries. A simple before/after/wrap option won't reveal the identity of the method in which the call is made.

I'm looking for a way to inject a logging aspect using annotations. Something like:

```
@LogMethodName
class enhancedLoggingClass{
  void foo(){
     logger.info("some message");
  }
}
```

And in some code/DSL I would write something like:

```
filter Methods with LogMethodName attribute OR inherited attribute from class
for each method:
  find call to Logger(String s, *)
  change to Logger(method.getName() + s, *)
```

In the past, in a C# 2.0 project a colleague tried out writing "shadow" code in which we could do anything. But this bypassed the tooling and made debugging not work, etc. So that was ditched.

Any suggestion are welcome.

Comment: `find call to Logger` This literally means introspection. AOP cannot do this. It's only Before, After, and Around (and other variants for throws).

Comment: is creating your own logger interface an option? If so, I wonder if `StackWalker` would be an option for you

Comment: So you can log the method name before/after method execution, but you cannot look for log calls inside the actual method.

Comment: @George thanks.
I understand that AspectJ or AOP will probably not work.
Filtering the call to Logger and getting the calling context is equivalent for my needs, but I wasn't sure how to designate the context calling method, so I went with a simplified "syntax"

Comment: Are you using a framework may be like Spring-Aop, or directly using aspectJ?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. Of course both AspectJ and Spring AOP give you access to the intercepted method name. But because you did not disclose your aspect code, I cannot tell you what is wrong with it. Please edit the question, providing additional details, ideally an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please read).